# How to prevent for hyphenated words in pdf output with Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I'm working with Rmarkdown and my output is a pdf document. When reading the pdf, I noticed that so many words are printed incomplete (hyphenated) such as "ar- rojan" and "progra- mación" (which should be "arrojan" and "programación").

Note: My words are complete in my `Rmd` file

This is how text appears in the pdf output:

```
   Los operadores <, >, <=, >=, == y != se denominan “lógicos” o “booleanos” porque nos ar­-
   rojan como resultado TRUE si se cumple la condición o comparación o FALSE en caso contrario.

   Sin embargo, R, al igual que la mayoría de los lenguajes de progra­-
   mación distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas (“case sensitive”),
```

Based on my little experience with `Rmarkdown`, I guess in the `YAML` section I must include some option to prevent that kind of behaviour. (What I need is something like the Microsoft Word function "Justify"). I found that `ragged2e` should help in this kind of situations so I included it in my `YAML` and then I use the `\justify` command before my text as follows:

```
---
title: "--"
author: ""
date: "Abril 2020"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
mainfont: Times New Roman
header-includes:
- \usepackage{titling}
- \pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\huge\bfseries}
- \posttitle{\end{flushleft}}
- \preauthor{\begin{flushleft}\Large}
- \postauthor{\end{flushleft}}
- \predate{\begin{flushleft}\large}
- \postdate{\end{flushleft}}
- \usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
fontsize: 12pt
urlcolor: blue
linestretch: 1.15
---

\justify

Rest of the document
```

My problem is that this is not printing my output as expected so I appreciate any suggestion or comment.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5036/how-to-prevent-latex-from-hyphenating-the-entire-document/5039

Comment: Thank you! That really worked!

Comment: Don't use `\justify`, that's an environment and not a macro. The macro is `\justifying`